# unable to execute python script from php

Tags: php, python

I want to execute Python script from PHP file. I am able to execute simple python script like:

```
print("Hello World")
```

but when I want to execute following script, nothing happens

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.converter = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg"
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("/var/www/dev.com/public_html/track.mp3")
sound.export("/var/www/dev.com/public_html/test.mp3", format="mp3", bitrate="96k")
```

and same script works fine when I execute it from terminal. here is my php script:

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/dev.com/public_html/index.py");
echo $output;
```

I have also tried following method but no luck:

```
$output = array();
$output = passthru("/usr/bin/python /var/www/dev.com/public_html/index.py");
print_r($output);
```

please help me

Comment: I have also tried other solution available on the stackoverflow. they all works to print "Hello World"  but not work for my above script.

Comment: You environment will be different when running inside a bash shell for example compared to shell_exec. If you know which environment variables are missing you can use `putenv("VARIABLE=value");` to set them via the PHP script.

Comment: try adding logging, and proper coding pracices by putting your code into a function that you invoke & catch occuring exceptions that you then log. Test by provoking an error so you verify that the logging works. Then try it out through PHP

Comment: yes. I this is due to missing environment variables. but I don't know how to set them from PHP

Comment: I have tried putenv('PATH=/usr/bin/ffmpeg:$PATH which ffmpeg'); but it is not working

Comment: "no luck" is like no debug info. Read _what_ error occurrs and debug it right away. No crystal balls around..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's `passthru` function does not have the elegant method for which you may be searching of passing environment variables.  If you must use `passthru`, then export your variables directly in the command:

```
passthru("SOMEVAR=$yourVar PATH=$newPATH ... /path/to/executable $arg1 $arg2 ...")
```

If you are inclined toward `shell_exec`, you may appreciate `putenv` for the slightly cleaner interface:

```
putenv("SOMEVAR=$yourVar");
putenv("PATH=$newPATH");
echo shell_exec("/path/to/executable $arg1 $arg2 ...");
```

If you are open to a more robust (if tedious) approach, consider [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php):

```
$cmd = "/path/to/executable arg1 arg2 ..."

# Files 0, 1, 2 are the standard "stdin", "stdout", and "stderr"; For details
# read the PHP docs on proc_open.  The key here is to give the child process a
# pipe to write to, and from which we will read and handle the "passthru"
# ourselves
$fileDescriptors = array(
    0 => ["pipe", "r"],
    1 => ["pipe", "w"],
    2 => ["pipe", "w"]
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = [
    'PATH' => $newPATH,
    'SOMEVAR' => $someVar,
    ...
];

# "pHandle" = "Process handle".  Note that $pipes is new here, and will be
# given back to us
$pHandle = proc_open($cmd, $fileDescriptors, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

# crucial: did proc_open work?
if ( is_resource( $pHandle ) ) {
    # $pipes is now valid
    $pstdout = $pipes[ 1 ];

    # Hey, whaddya know?  PHP has just what we need...
    fpassthru( $pstdout );

    # Whenever you proc_open, you must also proc_close.  Just don't
    # forget to close any open file handles
    fclose( $pipes[0] );
    fclose( $pipes[1] );
    fclose( $pipes[2] );
    proc_close( $pHandle );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestion but it is not working

Comment: @Rajinder That implies a typo or something else awry with your setup.  This is well-known paradigm, and I have just tested again to confirm it works.  If the community is going to help, you will need to provide more information.  "It is not working" is not a useful response.  _How_ is it not working?  What did you actually try?  What error messages did you receive?

Answer (score 2):

Acc to your reply, as you want to execute the python script from PHP

I was able to execute it using the following code

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/var/www/yourscript.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

Please use the above PHP code with the same python script.
Try to run the python script as a GCI script first to make sure it is working and set the permissions to public directory and script as I mentioned before

===================old ans============================

From what you asked, I guess this is what you are trying to do is that you are trying to run it as a CGI script like http://localhost/yourscript.py

**And why are you using PHP to execute python script when you can run it directly as a CGI script?**

here is what you need to do to make it work like a web page:

1. enable python CGI in apache ( or in the web server you are using ).
2. put the script in CGI configured directory
3. add proper code to your script to make it work as a CGI script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.converter = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("/var/www/dev.com/public_html/track.mp3")
sound.export("/var/www/dev.com/public_html/test.mp3", format="mp3", bitrate="96k")

print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print ""
print ""
print ""
print "Done/ you can perform some conditions and print useful info here"
print ""
```

4. Give permissions to the script and make the public directory writable
5. Access the script http://localhost/your-path-to-script.py

I was able to run this properly.
let me know if that's not your case if you want something else

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My requirement is run python script from PHP. because my main app in PHP but I want to run some script from python

Comment: @Rajinder, I have edited my post with the working PHP code please check and do let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: @Rajinder, did you get a chance to check my updated answer?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I did this code.

```
<?php
chdir('/home/pythontest') ; // python code dir
$commandline="/usr/bin/python3 test.py parameter" ;
exec($commandline, $output, $error) ;
echo $output ;
?>
```

If you need to set some environments for python, add environment vars like this.

```
$commmandline="LANG=en_US.utf8 LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 /usr/bin/python3 ..." ;
```

and check the httpd log.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestion but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

**Check this:**

The apache user has to be in sudoers file, better you don't give sudo to apache instead give apache (www-data) user right to run your python program

put first line in your python script: `#!/usr/bin/env python` so the script knows which program to open it with..

then,

change group:

```
chgrp www-data /path/to/python-script.py
```

make it executabe:

```
chmod +x /path/to/python-script.py
```

then try it:

```
shell_exec("/path/to/python-script.py");
```

I hope this will work! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestion but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can also exec ffmpeg directly without python:

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -b:a 96k out.mp3");
echo $output;
```

[ffmpeg docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3)

Answer (score 0):

Answered in 2022.

In php 8.0 and above the following method worked. Above answers are very useful but i am compiling few extra steps here.

PHP Code.

```
$output = shell_exec("python3 /var/www/python/test.py");
print_r($output);

exec('python3 --version 2>&1', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Trying both `shell_exe` and `exec`

1. Make sure the python file has executable permission and added to www-data group (if its ubuntu/debian systems) . `sudo chmod +x test.py` and `sudo chgrp www-data test.py`
2. Make sure the php.ini has disabled_functions line commented or empty.

`sudo vim sudo vim /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini`
`sudo vim sudo vim /etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini`

For both.

I compiled a simple video to make sure others dont spend more time figuring out the problem. https://youtu.be/t-f6b71jyoM